# Is the below code applicable in sencha touch 2.0

Tags: android, search, sencha-touch-2

Hello friends I am creating an app in sencha touch 2.0 in which i have added a search button to the toolbar.Now i want open a search field with transparent background like the below image.

[image]

While i run my project the logcat indicates me that error is in controller file.Below i am adding my controller class.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.search',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            groupList: "groupList"
        },
        control: {
            groupList: {
                        searchField: "searchField"            
            }
        }
    },
    searchField: function(){
      //  console.log("SearchField Tapped");
        if ( ! this.searchView)
        {
            this.searchView = this.render({
                xtype: 'searchView',
            });

            var cancelSearchBtn = this.searchView.query('#'+cancelSearchBtn)[0];

            cancelSearchBtn.setHandler(function(){
                this.searchView.hide();
            }, this);
        }

        this.searchView.show({
            type: 'slide',
            direction: 'up',
            duration: 500,
        });
    },
    launch: function(){
        alert('Hello search');
    },
});
```

I am getting the following error in logcat:-

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'this.render' [undefined] is not a function. at
file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/SearchController.js:18
```

Help me to get rid of the problem.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Who give me down vote give me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `render` method inside the controller. You need to create an instance of that component and then add it to the container you want it visible in (normally called Main).